# Inputs dinámicos no reaccionan cuando se hace submit del form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Estoy iniciando un proyecto y quiero hacerlo muy sencillo, estoy creando componentes y me estoy ayudando con Angular Material.
Estoy creando unos inputs basados en una interfaz, se ciclan y se arman y estos se ligan a un `FormGroup` cuando escribo en ellos y no tienen el formato correcto (Dado por `Validators`) bota el error, funciona como debe ser. El problema es cuando hago `submit` del `form`, si no escribo nada ni toco los inputs, no se validan, y creo que debería hacerlo, es decir, aunque el `FormControl` bindeado tenga errores no se muestran

Esta es la interfaz de los inputs

**foo-input.interface.ts**

```
export interface FooInput {
    type: string;
    label: string;
    placeholder: string;
    formControl: string;
    readonly: boolean;
    validators?: any[];
    hint?: string;
    error?: string;
    suffixIcon?: string;
    prefixIcon?: string;
}
```

Este es el HTML del componente

**foo-input.component.html**

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>
      {{ inputData.label }}
    </mat-label>
  
    <input matInput 
      [type]="inputData.type" 
      [placeholder]="inputData.placeholder"
      [readonly]="inputData.readonly"
      [formControlName]="inputData.formControl"
    >
    <mat-icon matSuffix *ngIf="inputData.suffixIcon">
      {{ inputData.suffixIcon }}
    </mat-icon>
  
    <mat-icon matPrefix *ngIf="inputData.prefixIcon">
      {{ inputData.prefixIcon }}
    </mat-icon>
  
    <mat-hint *ngIf="inputData.hint">
      {{inputData.hint}}
    </mat-hint>
    <mat-error
      *ngIf="inputData.error"
    >
      {{ inputData.error }}
    </mat-error>
  
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Dejo también el controlador de este HTML, no pondré los `.module.ts` por que todo se está importando bien ( Incluyendo `ReactiveFormsModule` y `FormsModule` )

**foo-input.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { FooInput } from '../../interfaces/foo-input.interface';

@Component({
  // tslint:disable-next-line: component-selector
  selector: 'foo-input',
  templateUrl: './foo-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./foo-input.component.scss']
})
export class FooInputComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() inputData: FooInput;
  @Input() form: FormGroup;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

}
```

Este es el HTML de cómo se están ciclando

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit()">
    <foo-input 
        *ngFor="let input of inputs"
        [form]="form" 
        [inputData]="input">
    </foo-input>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Y por último y no menos importante, cómo se arman dinámicamente esos inputs

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { FooInput } from '../app/interfaces/foo-input.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'foo';
  passwordRegex = '^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$';

  inputs: FooInput[] = [
    {
      label: 'Correo electrónico',
      type: 'email',
      placeholder: 'Escribe tu correo electrónico',
      readonly: false,
      formControl: 'email',
      error: 'El correo electrónico no tiene el formato correcto',
      validators: [ Validators.required, Validators.email ]
    },
    {
      label: 'Contraseña',
      type: 'password',
      placeholder: 'Escribe tu contraseña',
      readonly: false,
      formControl: 'pass',
      error: 'La contraseña no tiene el formato correcto',
      validators: [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern( this.passwordRegex ) ]
    }
  ];

  form = new FormGroup({});

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.inputs.forEach( (input: FooInput) => {
      this.form.addControl( input.formControl, new FormControl( null, input.validators ) );
    });
  }

  submit(): void {
    console.log( this.form );
    if ( this.form.valid ) {
      console.log( 'Valido' );
    } else {
      this.inputs.map( ( input: FooInput ) => this.form.controls[ input.formControl ].updateValueAndValidity() );
    }
  }

}
```

Intenté usar

```
form = new FormGroup({}, { updateOn: 'submit' });
```

Y ahora se validan al hacer submit, pero ya no hacen nada los controles cuando se hace `change`
Intenté con `'submit | change'` pero no me lo aceptó.

```
.updateValueAndValidity()
```

No hace nada

¿Cómo podría poner la validación a ambas funcionalidades, tanto `change` como `submit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El form tiene un método llamado [markAllAsTouched](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markallastouched) el cual de acuerdo a la documentación:

*"Marks the control and all its descendant controls as touched. (Marca el control y todos sus controles descendientes con el estado touched) "*

Al marcar todos los hijos directos cómo touched todos los errores deben mostarse, si usas el `updateOn:'submit'`
los controles no van a disparar ningún evento hasta el momento del submit del formulario, por lo que al editar algún control la validación no funcionaría.

Modificando tu código en el submit, podrías hacer algo cómo esto:

```
  submit(): void {
console.log( this.form );
if ( this.form.valid ) {
  console.log( 'Valido' );
} else {
  this.form.markAllAsTouched();
}
```

}